# How to apply CSS module with a dynamically created className

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-modules

I just started learning the use of CSS module.

What I am trying to do is to create a slider, and how I achieve its functionalities is by dynamically changing my className with "activeSlide", "nextSlide", and "lastSlide". However, I have an issue with CSS module, where I don't know what to put in my className for dynamic positioning and applying CSS property corresponding to each one of the position at the same time. How could I achieve both functionalities within one className using CSS module.

Here is my index.jsx file,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {FiChevronRight, FiChevronLeft} from 'react-icons/fi';
import reviewdata from './reviewdata';
import styles from './index.module.css';


export default function Review(){

    const randomizer =()=>{
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random()* (people.length))
        return number;
    }

    const [people, setPeople]= useState(reviewdata);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(randomizer());

    useEffect(()=>{
        const lastIndex = people.length - 1;
        if (index < 0){
            setIndex(lastIndex);
        } 
        if (index > lastIndex){
            setIndex(0);
        }
    },[index,people]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        let slider = setInterval(()=>{
            setIndex(index + 1);
        },4000)
        return ()=> clearInterval(slider)
    },[index])

    return (
        <section className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.title}>
                <h2>Reviews</h2>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.review_main}>
                {people.map((person, personIndex)=>{
                    const {id, username, userphoto, description, reviewphoto, star} = person;
                    
                    let position = 'nextSlide';

                    if(personIndex === index){
                        position = 'activeSlide';
                    }
                    
                
                    if(personIndex === index - 1 || (index === 0 && personIndex === people.length - 1)){
                        position = 'lastSlide';
                    }

                    return (
                        // still need to fix styles with dynamic position
                        <article className={`${styles.article} ${styles.position}`} key={id}> 
                            <img src={userphoto} alt={username} className={styles.person_img}/>
                            <h4>{username}</h4>
                            <p className={styles.title}>{star}</p>
                            <p className={styles.text_review}>{`"${description}"`}</p>
                            <img className={styles.review_img} src={reviewphoto} alt={username} />
                        </article>

                    )
                })}
                <button className={styles.prev} onClick={()=> setIndex(index - 1)}>
                    <FiChevronLeft/>
                </button>
                <button className={styles.next} onClick={()=> setIndex(index + 1)}>
                    <FiChevronRight/>
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Here is my index.module.css, where I am only showing the article tag part.

```
article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: var(--transition);
}
article.activeSlide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
article.lastSlide {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
article.nextSlide {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using css module in react, you don't need to use `article.activeSlide`. As it is just one module related css.  Use `activeSlide` in css file and `style[position]` where you want to use it

Comment: It works now! I simply changed ```className={`${styles.article} ${styles.position}`}``` to ```className={styles[position]}```. I didn't know you could use []. I don't think CSS module included that in their doc. Could you explain a bit more as to how ```{styles[position]}``` works as opposed to ```{styles.position}``` not working since I previously tried?

Comment: it is destructing syntax of javascript. `styles[position]` resolved into dynamic name you assigned earlier. You can view more details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment